# Animating container height when inserting child

Tags: javascript, css

I want a smooth transition of the height of a container when after inserting a child element.

```js
const cont = document.querySelector('.cont')
    
setTimeout(create,1000)
setTimeout(create,2000)
setTimeout(create,3000)

function create(){
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = 'some text'
  cont.appendChild(div)
}
```

```css
.cont {
    border:1px solid red;
    transition: all .09s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont"></div>
```

Comment: What did you tried ? What's not working ?

Comment: the height is not being transitioned. probably because it is auto by default?

Comment: Something like this: https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/bjdpBK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

And then also applying the class to the blocks you are adding.

```js
const cont = document.querySelector('.cont')
    
setTimeout(create,1000)
setTimeout(create,2000)
setTimeout(create,3000)

function create(){
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = 'some text'
  div.className = 'block'
  cont.appendChild(div)
}
```

```css
.cont{
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  animation-name: blockanim;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes blockanim {
    from {max-height: 0px;}
    to {max-height: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="cont"></div>
```